# Having issues with Kivy RecycleView data

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am having a strange issue when using Kivy's RecycleView. When trying to pass in a list of dictionaries using a custom widget I made as the viewclass it seems to create the correct number of widgets, however the actual values don't seem to get passed through, resulting in a correct number of "default" widgets. Here is a runnable example I created of the problem I am having:

main.py:

```
from kivy.app import App
import view


class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return view.PostRV()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = MainApp()
    app.run()
```

main.kv:

```
<RVContainer>:
    multiselect: True
    touch_multiselect: True
    height: self.minimum_height
    cols: 1
    default_size_hint: 1, None
    default_size: None, dp(110)
    size_hint_y: None
```

view.py:

```
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.graphics import Color, RoundedRectangle
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.recyclegridlayout import RecycleGridLayout


class PostRV(RecycleView):

    def __init__(self, **var_args):
        super(PostRV, self).__init__(**var_args)

        self.data = [
            {'date': 'a date', 'time': 'a time', 'name': 'a name'},
            {'date': 'another date', 'time': 'another time', 'name': 'another name'}
        ]  # this data does not seem to pass through properly

        self.add_widget(RVContainer())

        self.size_hint = 1, 1
        self.viewclass = Post


class RVContainer(RecycleGridLayout):
    pass
    

# below this line is the custom widget "Post" which I split into multiple classes for easier control and clarity

class Post(AnchorLayout):

    date = StringProperty('')
    time = StringProperty('')
    name = StringProperty('')

    def __init__(self, **var_args):
        super(Post, self).__init__(**var_args)

        self.anchor_y = 'center'
        self.anchor_x = 'center'
        self.size_hint = 1, None
        self.height = '110dp'

        self.add_widget(PostContainer(date=self.date, time=self.time, name=self.name))


class PostContainer(GridLayout):

    date = StringProperty('')
    time = StringProperty('')
    name = StringProperty('')

    def __init__(self, **var_args):
        super(PostContainer, self).__init__(**var_args)

        self.cols = 2
        self.padding = '12dp'
        self.size_hint = (None, None)
        self.width = Window.size[0] / 1.05
        self.height = '100dp'

        self.add_widget(PostShellOne(date=self.date, time=self.time, name=self.name))
        self.add_widget(PostShellTwo())

        self.bind(pos=self.update_rect, size=self.update_rect)

        with self.canvas.before:
            Color(1, 1, 1, .7)
            self.rect = RoundedRectangle(size=self.size, pos=self.pos, radius=[10])

    def update_rect(self, *args):
        self.rect.pos = self.pos
        self.rect.size = self.size
        self.width = Window.size[0] / 1.05


class PostShellOne(GridLayout):

    date = StringProperty('')
    time = StringProperty('')
    name = StringProperty('')

    def __init__(self, **var_args):
        super(PostShellOne, self).__init__(**var_args)

        self.rows = 3

        name_label = Label(text=self.name, color=(0, 0, 0, 1))
        date_label = Label(text=self.date, color=(0, 0, 0, 1))
        time_label = Label(text=self.time, color=(0, 0, 0, 1))

        self.add_widget(name_label)
        self.add_widget(time_label)
        self.add_widget(date_label)


class PostShellTwo(Button):

    def __init__(self, **var_args):
        super(PostShellTwo, self).__init__(**var_args)

        self.text = 'button'
        self.background_color = (0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.background_normal = ''

        self.bind(pos=self.update_rect, size=self.update_rect)

        with self.canvas.before:
            Color(0, 0, 0, .4)
            self.rect = RoundedRectangle(size=self.size, pos=self.pos, radius=[40])

    def update_rect(self, *args):
        self.rect.pos = self.pos
        self.rect.size = self.size
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RecycleView` works by creating instances of the `viewclass` (`Post` in your code), and then assigning the values from the `data` dictionary. So the `__init__()` methods of your `Post` classes create their child classes and pass in the current values of `name`, `date`, and `time`. But those values are still the default values of `''` at that time. Then, when the actual values of `name`, `date`, and `time` get set for the `Post` instance, it is too late, and the values are not passed to the children of the `Post` instance.

A way to fix this is to use the kivy language, since it does automatic binding to the `StringProperty` variables. So, you can expand your `main.kv` to include the `Post` class and its children:

```
<RVContainer>:
    multiselect: True
    touch_multiselect: True
    height: self.minimum_height
    cols: 1
    default_size_hint: 1, None
    default_size: None, dp(110)
    size_hint_y: None
<Post>:
    anchor_y: 'center'
    anchor_x: 'center'
    size_hint: 1, None
    height: '110dp'
    PostContainer:
        cols: 2
        padding: '12dp'
        size_hint: (None, None)
        width: app.root.size[0] / 1.05
        height: '100dp'
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: (1, 1, 1, .7)
            RoundedRectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
                radius: [10]

        PostShellOne:
            rows: 3
            Label:
                text: root.name
                color: 0,0,0,1
            Label:
                text: root.date
                color: 0,0,0,1
            Label:
                text: root.time
                color: 0,0,0,1
        PostShellTwo:
            text: 'button'
            background_color: (0, 0, 0, 0)
            background_normal: ''
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: (0, 0, 0, .4)
                RoundedRectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos
                    radius: [40]
```

Note that the `Labels` in `PostShellOne` use the `StringProperty` values of the `Post` class, so they update automatically.

Then the `Post` classes can be defined more simply:

```
class Post(AnchorLayout):
    date = StringProperty('')
    time = StringProperty('')
    name = StringProperty('')


class PostContainer(GridLayout):
    pass


class PostShellOne(GridLayout):
    pass


class PostShellTwo(Button):
    pass
```

Comment: Alright this fixed the problem thank you so much for the help!